# Regex to match string NOT containing specific character or more than one character

Tags: regex, email, o365-flow

Trying to get .NET regex to recognize the following string (A), but not string (B). Specific requirements to use .NET flavor of regex.

```
(A) :: John Doe <JDoe@domain.com>
(B) :: John Doe <JDoe@domain.com>, Jane Dina <JDina@domain.com>
```

Have tried quite a few options here including the following, but haven't gotten it to work the way I need it to (for more context, this is going to be used in an Exchange Online Transport Rule to filter messages that have ONLY one recipient, no more than one.

```
^[^<]+<[^>]+>$ - fails, recognizes both
^.*(?=[^,])$ - fails, recognizes none
^[^,]$ - fails, recognizes both
```

Let me know if there are additional details I can provide.

Dustin

Comment: I think this pattern `^[^<]+<[^>]+>$` does not recognize the second, this pattern `^.*(?=[^,])$` does not match because it does not match the last `>`  and this pattern `^[^,]$` matches a   single char except a comma. Perhaps use a more exact pattern `^\([A-Z]\)\s+::\s+[^<]+<[^\s@<>]+@[^\s<>]+>$` https://regex101.com/r/kATLmJ/1

Comment: you can use [^<>]+@\w+.\w+